# keyboard equivalent of dragging the little black square to generate sequence

Tags: keyboard, spreadsheet, libreoffice-calc

What is the keyboard way of generating a sequence?

The pic below shows libre office calc. In order to generate the sequence of numbers 1 to 10. I simply enter few numbers of the sequence (in ascending order) one below the other. In this case three numbers. I select all three. And I click and drag the little black box as pointed out in the image until I reach my desired ending number.

How to achieve this via keyboard only?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Enter the first number of the sequence
2. Select the range to fill (<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd>)
3. Use <kbd>Alt</kbd> to navigate the menu: <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd>, <kbd>i</kbd>, <kbd>e</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd>

   This is a shortcut for `Edit`->`Fill`->`Series`

As a mnemonic, adapt the children's song "Old Macdonald," substituting IO (Input/Output) for the Enter key:

> Old Macdonald had a series of animals, (alt) E I E IO

Answer (score 3):

The keyboard equivalent to the requested function is placed under the `Edit`->`Fill`->`Series` command in the menu. In newer LibreOffice versions the location is `Sheet`->`Fill Cells`->`Series...`.

Before running the command, select the cells to be filled in by using <kbd>Shift</kbd> + navigation keys (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd> in the case of OP).

Then you may use [mnemonics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mnemonics_(keyboard)) for running the command. Or even better, set a custom keyboard shortcut via `Tools`->`Customize...`->`Keyboard`. In the dialog, select `Category = Edit`, `Function = Fill Series` and set for example <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> as the shortcut.

Answer (score 1):

According to [LibreOffice's Help page for Calc](https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Shortcut_Keys_for_Spreadsheets) there is no keyboard shortcut for that.

Answer (score 1):

Alt+s, i, e

The menu will be : **S**heet>F**i**ll Cells>S**e**ries

Answer (score 0):

shift + down to cell you wish the formula to be extended to (include the target formula cell(s) in the selection)

then,
Alt + s, i, d

Answer (score 0):

For Librecalc 7.5, this can be achieved by

1. Selecting the required cells using  `Shift + Down`
2. Autofill by using `Ctrl + D` . This is a shortcut for the command `Sheet -> Fill Cells -> Fill Down`